# performance issues when jdk8 version changed from 151 to 161

Tags: java-8

I have one simple web service (post) when running the tomcat with `jdk8 151`, getting the higher throughput while sending the request through JMeter. while with `jdk8 161/171` throughput is comparatively very low.

Comment: so... we are supposed to guess right?

Comment: @Eugene I think we're supposed to close it as "unclear"

Comment: i am also guessing, need some clue, how should we probe, tomact used is version 8, Jmeter3

Comment: what is unclear here, kindly let me know th eother details required..

Comment: more than happy to retract my close vote if the question can be improved, see 
 [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I suggest you run a CPU profile of both versions and compare what is taking much longer in the newer JVMs.

Comment: Re _"what is unclear here, kindly let me know the other details required"_, you could update your question with the JMeter output for throughput that prompted you to ask this question.